# How can a use-package stanza be configured a setting depending on another package's existence?

Tags: use-package

I have this `magit` configuration which automatically sets the magit commit message buffer to `evil` `INSERT` mode, but it assumes that `evil` is installed and active which may not be the case. How can I configure it so that it will only apply if `evil` is installed and active?

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-x g" . magit-status))
  :config
  (setq magit-ediff-dwim-show-on-hunks t)
  (add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook #'evil-insert-state)
  )
```

Comment: `featurep` can be used to check if a feature is present. You'd have to look up what feature `evil` provides and conditionally add the hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the evil-related section to load if/when evil is loaded, you could wrap it with `with-eval-after-load 'evil`, like so:

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-x g" . magit-status))
  :config
  (setq magit-ediff-dwim-show-on-hunks t)
  (with-eval-after-load 'evil
    (add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook #'evil-insert-state)))
```

If you want the whole magit config to only load if evil is loaded, you could use the `:after` keyword like so:

```
(use-package magit
  :ensure t
  :after evil
  :bind (("C-x g" . magit-status))
  :config
  (setq magit-ediff-dwim-show-on-hunks t)
  (add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook #'evil-insert-state))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use package has a `:if` directive that will

> Initialize and load only if EXPR evaluates to a non-nil value.

Adding that to your config will stop magit from being loaded if evil is not already loaded.

```
(use-package magit
  :if (featurep 'evil-mode)
  :ensure t
  :bind (("C-x g" . magit-status))
  :config
  (setq magit-ediff-dwim-show-on-hunks t)
  (add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook #'evil-insert-state)
  )
```